# How to Replace Thunar with PcManFM

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, thunar, pcmanfm

How should I do to replace Thunar with PCManFM in Xubuntu? I have tried but just removing Thunar and instaling PCManFM. And PCManFM doesn't succeed Thunar features like integrated with Dropbox, starting at startup, my filesystem not appearing on places, etc.

Thank you

Comment: sounds as if you answered your own question, pcmanfm does not have the features you want.

Comment: it means Lubuntu have less features than Xubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Developer *PCMan* is a medical student and hence a busy man. This and other reasons resulted in PCManFM being poorly maintained.

Developer *ignorantguru* took up the lead and developed [SpaceFM](http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/), a worthy and more powerful successor to PCManFM. SpaceFM features many easily installable [user-contributed plugins](https://github.com/IgnorantGuru/spacefm/wiki/plugins) —some of yours truly— that will cater for many of your needs.

Follow the [instructions for installing SpaceFM on Ubuntu](https://github.com/IgnorantGuru/spacefm/wiki/Debian) (and Debian).

After installation, run `exo-preferred-applications` and choose `spacefm` as the default file manager:

[image: exo-preferred-applications]

You also will have to change a few MIME defaults:

```
xdg-mime default spacefm.desktop inode/directory application
```

The file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` should also be edited.

Look for the line containing `inode/directory=thunar.desktop;`
and change it to read `inode/directory=spacefm.desktop;`

It is possible that you also will need to perform a similar edit of `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` under administrative rights.

Finally, [`mimeopen -a filename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mimeopen) might be helpful in debugging MIME type settings.

If you are using XFCE like I do, there remains one caveat. Links on the desktop will continue to open with Thunar. (Thunar cannot be uninstalled because of other dependant packages.) It seems that this behaviour for opening desktop links is hard-wired in XFCE 4.8.